# Is there idiomatic way to handle "reference or create and use reference to it" pattern in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I realized that very often in Rust I need to do a following pattern:

```rust
let variable = &some_ref;

let variable = if something {
  let new_variable = create_something();
  &new_variable
} else {
  variable
};

// Use variable here
```

In other words, I need to either use an existing reference or create a new owned value and use a reference to it.
But the problem is if I do it like in the example above the `new_variable` does not live long enough, it's dropped at the end of the first `if` clause.

Is there a idiomatic way to structure the code nicely to achieve the "use reference or create new and use reference to new" way? Or I just have to copy/make function for the code that uses `variable` 2 times - one for branch where I already have reference and another for branch where I create a owned value and that use reference to it?

Here is real-world example of how I usually use function (`overlay_with_u32` in this case) to copy the behavior between 2 branches:

```rust
let source = &source;

if is_position_negative(x, y) {
  let source = crop(source, x, y);
  overlay_with_u32(destination, &source, x, y);
} else {
  overlay_with_u32(destination, source, x, y);
};
```

Comment: I think you'd be best off declaring your `new_variable` above the `if` block without a value, then assigning to it and updating your reference where needed. The compiler will also render the temp variable unusable by the rest of your code because it may be uninitialized: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=761ab435e70c21a55a56f76d93620fa6

Comment: This sounds like a good usage of [Cow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), which allows you to either own the data or have a reference to non-owned data as if you had a reference, which fits your case.

Comment: I think your new example is more confusing than the original, because we don't know what `overlay_with_u32` does. A minimal reproducible example might help you get answers more specific to your exact issue.

Comment: @JeremyMeadows Seems like your playground example is what I wanted, it works, thanks.`overlay_with_u32` is not really relevant, it just uses reference to the `source`, it could do anything, the idea itself what matters and it happens often in my code.

Comment: @BlackBeans thanks! Will take a look into `Cow` as well, I never had a need or opportunity to look into that smart pointer in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)(Clone-on-write) for this.

The `Cow` type is an emum of *either* an owned or a borrowed value:

```
pub enum Cow<'a, B>
where
    B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized,
{
    Borrowed(&'a B),
    Owned(<B as ToOwned>::Owned),
}
```

You could use it something like (variables renamed for clarity):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

let variable_ref = &some_ref;

let variable = if something {
    let variable_created = create_something();
    Cow::Owned(variable_created)
} else {
    Cow::Borrowed(variable_ref)
};
```

Functions that accept a `&T` can be given a `&Cow<T>`, which will automatically be deferenced as you'd expect:

```
let variable: Cow<'_, i32> = Cow::Owned(3);
do_stuff(&variable);

fn do_stuff(i: &i32) {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's either `Cow` or declaring variable before `if` block as @JeremyMeadows suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `Cow` may be the right thing to do, but here I'm going to suggest another approach, that might be cheaper (especially if the types are `Drop`-less, in this case it is zero-cost except it may require more stack space), but requires more code and may be less obvious.

Rust allows you to declare a variable but initialize it conditionally, as long as the compiler can prove that the variable is always initialized if it is used. You can exploit this fact to longer the lifetime of a variable inside a scope; instead of:

```rust
let reference = {
    let variable = ...;
    &variable
};
```

You can write:

```rust
let variable;
let reference = {
    variable = ...;
    &variable
};
```

But now `variable` lives long enough.

Applied to your case, it looks like:

```rust
let variable = &some_ref;
let new_variable;

let variable = if something {
    new_variable = create_something();
    &new_variable
} else {
    variable
};
```

Comment: _"Using `Cow` may be the right thing to do"_ -- `Cow` is probably a good generally applicable answer to the problem stated in the question's title, but it's not zero cost. Extending the lifetime, as in your answer, is certainly better whenever the problem is localised like this specific case.